# AP BC Calculus Resources

Tags: calculus, reference-request, online-resources

I am studying for the [AP BC Calculus Exam](http://www.collegeboard.com/student/testing/ap/sub_calbc.html) and I know about the [free response questions](http://www.collegeboard.com/student/testing/ap/calculus_bc/samp.html) from AP Central, and the Multiple Choice Collection.  I was wondering if anyone here knew of where to obtain more problems?  At least a collection of problems similar to those that appear on the BC Exam.

I realize this is not a question about an actual math question, but I don't feel very confident in my math ability so I want more problems to solve.

Ps. I don't have alot of cash, so I can't afford to buy barron's books or any test prep books.  The local libaray doesn't have any -someone check the book out but never returned it, and the book store doesn't like it when you just sit there working out problems and you don't buy the book.

Comment: Is AP BC [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Placement_Calculus)?

Comment: @Marin, yes, I will add the links to my question.

Comment: See [this discussion post](http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/ap-tests-preparation/1348023-guide-self-studying-ap-calculus-bc.html): recommendations from someone "whose been there", with some links to online material, practice exams, and many other suggestions! See for example this [pdf compilation](http://staff.4j.lane.edu/~windom/AP/ap%20multiple%20choice.pdf) of old tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Free online resources:**

1. [*The AP Calculus Problem Book*](http://crunchymath.weebly.com/uploads/8/2/4/0/8240213/apcalcprobbook.pdf) - This is one of the best sources of AP Calculus probems, containg 2000+ AB/BC problems.
2. [*Calculus I Practice Problems*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/getfile.aspx?file=B,8,P) [(Solutions)](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/getfile.aspx?file=B,8,S) - Practice problems from *Paul's Online Notes*.
3. [*Calculus II Practice Problems*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/getfile.aspx?file=B,2,P) [(Solutions)](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/getfile.aspx?file=B,2,S) - Practice problems from *Paul's Online Notes*. This is not yet complete, but a good resource nonetheless.
4. [CalcReview](https://sites.google.com/site/learnapcalc/ap-calculus-bc) - This contains multiple choice problems similar to those on the AP exam, and links to free video lectures.
5. [*Cornell Good Questions*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~GoodQuestions/GQbysubject_pdfversion.pdf) - This contains interesting Calculus AB conceptual questions.

**Print resources (you can probably get these from school/local library):**

1. [*Preparing for the AP Calculus BC Examination*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1886018162) - This is almost certainly the best resource for preparing for the AP Calculus exams, but it is hard to find. Also, the solution manual must be purchased separately.
2. [*Be Prepared for the AP calculus Exam*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0982477554) - This is another great resources, but may be hard to find.
3. [*Barron's AP Calculus*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1438002041) - You almost certainly have a copy of this in your school library, and its not a bad resource.
4. [*Schaum's 3000 Solved Problems in Calculus*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635343) - Huge source of Calculus AB/BC problems.