# What should a high school student do before AP Calculus?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm about to take AP Calculus next year. I know it's gonna be hard, so i'm trying to get at least something in my head therefore i won't get too behind. I really would like to learn more about this amazing subject.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286680/ap-bc-calculus-resources), or similar ones (you can search this site).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Topics to master before taking Calculus AB?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345645/topics-to-master-before-taking-calculus-ab)